# Can we use Sitecore TDS with Visual Studio 2022 Preview 2?

Tags: tds, visual-studio

On a new machine, I tried installing VS 2022 and TDS but TDS gives an error that it doesn't detect VS in that system.

So the question is - Can we use Sitecore TDS with Visual Studio 2022 Preview 2 by tweaking something?

Is [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/VisualStudio/comments/ownzo2/extensions_for_vs_2022_preview/) something that is affecting here?

Comment: I think it`s not possible rigth now, because of VS 2022 is 64 bit and we are waiting while all VS 3rd parties software (like Resharper) will be updated for new 64 version.

Comment: @x3mxray see my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### UPDATE: Support for VS 2022 was added recently in TDS.

You have to use the x64 `.msi` file which is included in the most recent [TDS version 6.0.0.34](https://www.teamdevelopmentforsitecore.com/Download/TDS-Classic) released on *November 12th, 2021* while VS 2019 only works with the x86 `.msi` (also included).

---

As of now it is not possible to use TDS extension and many more VS extensions in Visual Studio 2022.

Reason is because VS 2022 is 64-bit and so far all VS extensions in marketplace were being built as 32-bit for VS 2019 and earlier versions.

All third parties extensions (like ReSharper) will be updated for new 64-bit version as we approach general availability of VS 2022 then it should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

The latest release of Sitecore TDS was released in July 2021.

[image]

VS 2022 Preview 2 was released in 22nd of July.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes-preview

On the release notes of the latest TDS doesn't mention anything related to VS 2022 .

Comment: Sitecore for Visual Studio is not the same as TDS

Comment: @RichardSeal thanks Richard, my mistake I made the wrong print screen.